# Grid filtering is only filtering last column

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I tried this code for filtering all columns of my grid view by a text box, but it just filters the last column of my grid. How can I change it? What is wrong in my code? My first column is 2 and the last is 4. My for loop started with 2 and ended with 4, but when I try this ""(i=2;i<4;i++) it shows me my column with index of 3.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        // Client Side Search (Autocomplete)
        // Get the search Key from the TextBox
        // Iterate through the 1st Column.
        // td:nth-child(1) - Filters only the 1st Column
        // If there is a match show the row [$(this).parent() gives the Row]
        // Else hide the row [$(this).parent() gives the Row]

        $('#filter').keyup(function (event) {
            var searchKey = $(this).val();
            for (i =2; i<5; i++) {
                $("#gvwHuman_ctl00 tr  td:nth-child(" + i + ")").each(function () {
                // $("#gvwHuman_ctl00 tr td:nth-child(" + i + ")").each(function () {
                    var cellText = $(this).text();
                    if (cellText.indexOf(searchKey) >= 0) {
                        $(this).parent().show();
                    } else {
                        $(this).parent().hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see why this question is downvoted and voted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for each cell of the row, you show or hide the row. So only the last one matters.

You could do this :

```
       // 1 : hide all rows
       $("#gvwHuman_ctl00 tr").hide();

       // 2 : show the row if there is one match
       for (i =2; i<5; i++) {
            $("#gvwHuman_ctl00 tr  td:nth-child(" + i + ")").each(function () {
            // $("#gvwHuman_ctl00 tr td:nth-child(" + i + ")").each(function () {
                var cellText = $(this).text();
                if (cellText.indexOf(searchKey) >= 0) {
                    $(this).closest('tr').show();
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your help sorry because i had not any time  for editing my question i cant ask my question in good manner  i try more than this and  ask good shape question in future  your answer  is very useful thanks a lot